# better Idea than singleton to use for global variable

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have a queue that should be used by some classes.

it is the same queue for all of the classes so I thought maybe I will put the queue in static class as a static member.
But I understand this is not so good OOP.(although I thought that singleton is one of the design pattern)
so I would like an Idea for implement this queue,
I will need it to be unique and accessible to all the classes  as all the classes use the same queue.

Comment: are you using an IoC container?

Comment: Create a singletone class which contains a Queue (or ConcurrentQueue) and expose all the needed functionality in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say is that your classes share some context and this context contains one queue. We can say that your classes depend on this context.

The reason for which the singleton pattern is not a good idea is because it uses the global (static) context as the common context. This is limiting for two reasons:

1. It is not easy to clearly identify the dependencies of your classes, and therefore it is not easy to set them up under different environments (such as a unit testing environment).
2. It is totally impossible to have two instances of this context run side by side.

So, an easy solution is to put all the dependencies of your classes inside a context class and then link all your classes with an instance of this class.

Another, more advanced, solution is to use a Dependency Injection framework.

Comment: I would argue that a DI framework is less complex than your proposed solution. sure. It's a new concept to grasp, but it produces cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make it a Singleton as this would be globally visible to all classes and layers in your program. Give the parts which need access to the queue the reference to the queue itself. So you clearly determine which part of your software has access to it.

I had very bad experiences with software projects which had too many singletons aka "XyzManager" in it as they were used from any part of the software in a wild way. Try to avoid global variables and Singletons if you can. Better give references into your objects to things they should have access to.